# Why is checking a variable with is to non-type is not an error

Tags: c#

I have seen many colleagues by mistake use

```
x is true
```

to check if the variable is `true`.

Independently of whether it is necessary to use `is` or the correct `==` to check if a boolean is true, I'd like to understand why this is not a compilation error.

The documentation[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator) of `is` states:

> The is operator checks if the result of an expression is compatible with a given type.

AFAIK `true` is not a type.

Interestingly this also works for integers.

Update:
I tried it out with the [online editor provided by W3](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/trycs.php?filename=demo_compiler) and there it used to be an error. Has pattern matching changed this behaviour with C# 8?

So does `x is true` do the same as `x == true` in C# 8 (even without the `{}`?

Comment: This is part of C# 7, actually. It's pattern matching against a [constant pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/pattern-matching#constant-pattern). If `x` is of type `object` (for example), then `x == true` is a compile error, while `x is true` checks if `x` is a `bool` and `true`. If `x` is itself a `bool`, then arguably neither expression is appropriate: just `x` suffices.

Comment: @JeroenMostert After asking the question a kept reading the many links in those pages and at some point found exactly the behaviour you describe. Now I feel like a bit stupid for asking it.